# Assigning the same font to multiple controls C#

Tags: c#, fonts, controls, dispose

What is the best practice for disposing of Font objects in C# used in several different controls?

As an example, I have several text boxes, labels, and buttons to which I want to assign the same font.
I thought of using the following code:

```
using (Font f = new Font("Calibri", 10.0f))
{
    textbox1.Font = f;
    textbox2.Font = f;
    label1.Font = f;
    button1.Font = f;
}
```

The problem is that after using `f` once I can't use it again and I have to declare a new Font object. 
What is the best practice for these situations? Should I use the following code?

```
Font f;
f = new Font(...);
textbox1.Font = f;
f.Dispose();

f = new Font(...);
textbox1.Font = f;
...
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's wrong with the upper code? It's working for me

Comment: You can use it multiple times (first example) but you can't wrap your code inside a "using" statement (or it'll be disposed). 2nd question: WHY you dispose your font? You'll still need it...

Comment: The code above works up until I assign text into the text boxes. If the line: textbox1.Text = "Some Text" is outside the 'using' block, the font won't change. And disposing of fonts is just a good practice thing [using Statement - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: @Trout see my answer. Dispose finite resources is always a good practice but it must be done AFTER you used it. If you dispose it while still in use it's like you throw away food from your dish before you even started to eat it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you're disposing your font just after its creation? You still need it `(Dispose()` should be called when you won't use it any more). You can use code from both examples, they're OK when removing `Dispose()` and `using`:

```
Font f = new Font("Calibri", 10.0f);
textbox1.Font = f;
textbox2.Font = f;
label1.Font = f;
button1.Font = f;
```

Or (it's slightly less efficient because you allocate more unneeded resources unless `Font` constructor manages a kind of cache, I'm not sure about it):

```
textbox1.Font = new Font("Calibri", 10.0f);
textbox2.Font = new Font("Calibri", 10.0f);
label1.Font = new Font("Calibri", 10.0f);
button1.Font = new Font("Calibri", 10.0f);
```

**EDIT**
Little note about resource disposing: of course you should always dispose a resource each time it's possible (simple rule is to always call `Dispose()` for classes that implements `IDisposable`). That said you have to do it **after** you used it, not before. Let's see this code:

```
var font = font;
textbox1.Font = font;
font.Dispose();
```

Of course it won't work because `textbox1` has a reference to a disposed object (I don't know what will happen, an `ObjectDisposedException`? Just ignored?). `Dispose()` should be called only when you won't use that resource again in future and it's not the case because it'll be used by `textbox1` to draw its text. A proper use, for example is:

```
using (var font = new Font("Calibri", 10.0f))
{
    e.Graphics.DrawText(Text, font, Brushes.Black, ClientRectangle);
}
```

In this case `font` is used only by code inside `using` statement and it can be properly and safely disposed (even if in this case you'd better to avoid to create it each time and you should reuse it).

Comment: When Visual Studio builds component it uses the second method you showed, but each new statement holds the resource until the program dies. I don't know if this is the best thing to do. And theoretically you're first example should solve all my problems, but when I assign test into the text boxes the font isn't changed and it stays with the default font unless I assign a new Font instance to it. Maybe I didn't read it right, but they also explain it here: [TextBox.Font MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.font%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Trout if you're talking about _immutable_ it's something different. It means you can't change its properties once it has been created. It means that to change (for example) its size you have to create a new instance (but same instance can be shared across multiple controls). _Ambience_ is something else: if you do not assign a value to that property then it'll be inherited by parent (so if you change Form font then each control will inherit it even if you do not override its value for each one).

Comment: I'll leave my first comment to assert my stupidity in this subject, and I'll just say thanks :) For some reason I thought magic was happening backstage and only the 'new Font(...)' object was disposed, but the property was kept alive. And it doesn't throw an exception, which in my case is too bad...

Comment: @Trout well it's not such mad idea, immutable objects may be seen as read-only structs (copy by value) and in that case it makes sense. Personally I always hated this design decision in C#: "new" operator must be always used, both for reference and value types. I think it's pretty confusing (especially when you come from C++ and not Java).

Comment: Curiously, the OP's `using` block is correct code, since the `Font` object that is created therein will most likely never be used after it's done.  The `Control.Font` property is neither designed nor documented well; there are actually two backing fields for the property--one which holds a reference to the object which was used to "set" it, and one which holds a private reference to a `Font` the control creates for its own use.  Controls never dispose the object used to set their `Font` property, nor do they care if anything else does so.

Comment: @Trout: A `Font` actually contains two parts (which should probably have been handled by different classes): a collection of information about a font's typographical characteristics (typeface, encoding, size, etc.) along with a handle to a GDI font object which matches that style.  GDI handles need to be released, and calling `Dispose` on a font will release its handle, but when a control's `Font` property is set, it will ignore the GDI handle of the passed-in font and instead create a new font with a new handle.

Answer (score 0):

When the `Font` property of a control is set, the control will make note of the characteristics of the assigned font, and then generate a new `Font` object for its own use based upon that.  Reading the `Font` property will return a reference to the object that was used to set it, but that is the only use to which the passed-in object will be put once the control observes its characteristics.  Calling `Dispose` on a `Font` will prevent it from being used for drawing, but will not prevent controls from observing its characteristics and making their own (usable) `Font` object based upon them.  Indeed, one may assign a font to a control even after calling `Dispose` on it.

Arguably, what this indicates is that the `Font` property of a control should have been a different type from the `IDisposable` font which can be used directly for drawing, but since the Framework is what it is, it's best to simply recognize that the `Font` property of a control really works with "font characteristics" rather than with a `Font` object.